# Input string was not in a correct format powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to create a simple performance counter with powershell using an example code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605146/creating-editing-performance-counters-in-a-powershell-script-or-command-line). In the last line i replaced the variables with strings:

```
[System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Create("catname", "catinfo", [Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategoryType]::SingleInstance, $CounterCollection);
```

When i'm run the script, i get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Create" with "4" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\...\setup_test.ps1:9 char:56
+ [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Create <<<< ("catname", "catfaszom",     [Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategoryType]::SingleInstance, $CounterCollection); 
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I printed some extra info with

```
$error[0]|format-list -force
```

The additional result is:

```
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Create" with "4" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format." ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
                       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
                       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
                       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
                       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
                       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
                       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
                       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(String categoryName, String categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection counterData)
                       at Create(Object , Object[] )
                       at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)
                       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                       at System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.AuxiliaryMethodInvoke(Object target, Object[] arguments, MethodInformation methodInformation, Object[] originalArguments)
                       at System.Management.Automation.ParserOps.CallMethod(Token token, Object target, String methodName, Object[] paramArray, Boolean callStatic, Object valueToSet)
                       at System.Management.Automation.MethodCallNode.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Object value)
                       at System.Management.Automation.MethodCallNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)
                       at System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
                       at System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

What is wrong whit my code?

Update:

The whole code:

```
$ccdTypeName = 'System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationData'
$CounterCollection = New-Object System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationDataCollection

#create as many counters as we'd like, and add them to the collection. here's just one:
$CounterCollection.Add( (New-Object $ccdTypeName "TestCtr1", "Test counter 1 description", NumberOfItems32) )

#create the category with the counter collection
[System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Create("asd", "dasd", [Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategoryType]::SingleInstance, $CounterCollection);
$error[0]|format-list -force
```

I tried to run it on an another pc, and it worked without any errors.

Comment: Can you give the rest of your code (the way $CounterCollection is created) ?

Comment: Ok, you should evaluate $ccdTypeName, $CounterCollection.

Comment: Also check to make sure the PerformanceCounterCategory doesn't exist before trying to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It had nothing to do with Input string. First, i updated powershell from 2.0 to 3.0, then i got the right exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry.
```

The first result in google ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980178/cannot-load-counter-name-data-because-an-invalid-index-exception)) solved my problem. After opening an administrator command prompt and typed `lodctr /r`, my script worked without any problem.