# Why is powershell not recommended to manage performance counters?

Tags: powershell, wmi, performancecounter

I want to use powershell to manage performance counters because it doesn't require compiling like C#.

However, in [this article](https://aero971.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/add-performance-counters-through-powershell/) it is said that powershell is not recommended for this purpose.

Also, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605146/creating-editing-performance-counters-in-a-powershell-script-or-command-line) it was hinted that C# would be better than powershell because instances created within C# would be permanent.
I am not convinced about this though because I have tested it and it seems both C# application and powershell script have their instances deleted when they are closed.

So, is there any other reason that would make powershell not recommended to manage performance counters compared to C#?

Comment: Go ahead with PS thats what I can say. There is no harm in that. Even PS can support multi-instance counters

Comment: Such a kind of questions is off topic on SO

Comment: I don't think its clearly off-topic. The OP read that they should not use PowerShell. There very well could be non-biased technical reasons for it. While it might attract opinionated answers that does not exclusively mean its off topic.